# AsyncTask's doInBackground() does not execute (despite fresh instantiations) for some tasks

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

This error is common, but despite applying the most popular solutions for days, I keep getting stuck. I have several classes that extend AsyncTask.

Strange thing is **my `PostComment.java` does call doInBackground but `DownloadComments.java` does not**, despite them being in the same function one right after another. The order in which I call their execute does not matter.

*Bios.java* calls DownloadComments and PostComment

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
        case(R.id.Post):

        // Start DownloadComments
        // Execute doInBackground NOT CALLED
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            new DownloadComments().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "Clinton");
        } else {
            new DownloadComments().execute(candidate);
        }

        // Post Comment
        EditText commentHandler = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);
        String commentString = commentHandler.getText().toString();
        // Execute doInBackground IS CALLED
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            new PostComment().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, commentString, MainActivity.username, Integer.toString(MainActivity.PosterID));
        } else {
            new PostComment().execute(commentString, MainActivity.username, Integer.toString(MainActivity.PosterID));
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

PostComment.java (`extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>`)

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // Otherwise SocketException Connection reset by peer
    try {
        String comment = arg0[0];
        String username = arg0[1];
        String PosterName = arg0[2];


        // EDIT LINK
        String link = "http://particlecollider.net76.net/postComment.php";


        URL url = new URL(link);
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("comment", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(comment, "UTF-8")
                + "&"
                + URLEncoder.encode("UN", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        // Kill keep-alive property
        conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");


        // Write
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

        // Read
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

DownloadComments `extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` THIS METHOD IS NOT ENTERED AT ALL

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... passedIn) {
    try {
        String candidate = passedIn[0];
        String link = "http://particlecollider.net76.net/downloadComments.php?candidate="+candidate;
        int CommentsInLinearList;

    URL url = new URL(link);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    // Kill keep-alive property
    conn.setRequestProperty("connection", "close");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;

    // Read Server Response
    // Skip until it works
    while (!(line = reader.readLine()).contains("COMMENTLINEARLIST")) {
        // Finished
    }
    CommentsInLinearList = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    while (CommentsInLinearList > 0) {
        line = reader.readLine();
        sb.append(line);
        CommentsInLinearList--;
    }

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
    JSONArray myJSONArray = jObject.getJSONArray("CommentLinearList");
    if(myJSONArray != null) {
        for(int i=0; i<myJSONArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject targetComment = myJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Comment PushComment = new Comment(candidate);
            PushComment._ID = Integer.parseInt(targetComment.getString("ID"));
            PushComment._Candidate = candidate;
            PushComment._PosterID = Integer.parseInt(targetComment.getString("PosterID"));
            PushComment._ReplyToId = Integer.parseInt(targetComment.getString("ReplyToID"));
            PushComment._Rating = Integer.parseInt(targetComment.getString("Rating"));
            PushComment._Comment = targetComment.getString("Comment");
            // PushComment into candidateCommentArrayList
            candidateCommentArrayList.add(PushComment);
        }
        // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu., candidateCommentArrayList);
    }
    return sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
}
```

When debugging, it does not even enter doInBackground for DownloadComments

[image]

Please help. Let me know if I can add more details

Comment: It doesn't enter doInBackground of PostComments, but does it enter PostComments?

Comment: Yes it does, for both PostComments and DownloadComments the constructor is called. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Dit you put the breakpoint on the switch statement?

Comment: I did not, I was curious why it was going there. I had assumed that the debugger was not passing through there since mStatus was always either PENDING or RUNNING

Comment: I've been testing everything I can thing of. Right now I'm commenting out PostComment's `doInBackground` and I'm replacing it with DownloadComment's `doInBackground` and calling PostComment's wherever I called DownloadComments. Curiously it enters doInBackground when I do that, so the problem isn't an issue with the contents of the method. I wonder why it discriminates DownloadComments.java and not PostComment.java?

Comment: kk I'm starting to think some garbage is going on with THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR. I'm not sure what it is but reading around it can hold 5 threads? I've got lots of AsyncTasks so maybe that's why DownloadComments doesn't work. Strange though, I'm calling DC before PC. For now I'll try making DownloadComments2.java and see if that works favorably. Otherwise I'm going to use a disgusting workaround and combine both doInBackgrounds into one method.

Comment: DownloadComments2.java is virtually copypaste identical to DownloadComments.java. When I call that, doInBackground does execute. Curious, I'll accept any answer that can explain this behavior.